# Binomial Test - Subgroup vs. population using binom.test from R

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, multiple-comparisons

I have a group of users performing actions that have an outcome of error/no.error (in this case error is a success).

I want to compare each user to the population to see if their error identification rate is different from the rest of the population.

```
ten.user.list <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
ten.user.probs <-c(0.1,0.08,0.11,0.1,0.1,0.13,0.11,0.08,0.09,.10)

is.success <- c(0,1)
samples = 10000

user <- c(sample(ten.user.list, samples , replace = TRUE,prob = ten.user.probs))
success <- sample(is.success, samples, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.85, 0.15)) 

user.df <- data.frame(user,success)

### Create binom test to compare each user against the population
pop.avg <- sum(user.df$success)/nrow(user.df)


library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

bi.test.users <- user.df %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(bi.test = 
           purrr::map(data, function(df)
             broom::glance(
               binom.test(x = sum(df$success),
                          n = nrow(df),
                          p = pop.avg,
                          alternative = c("t"),
                          conf.level = 0.95
               )
             ))) %>%
  select(user, bi.test) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  arrange(p.value)
```

Giving me a table of

```
|user |  estimate| statistic|   p.value| parameter|  conf.low| conf.high|method              |alternative |
|:----|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|:-------------------|:-----------|
|j    | 0.1334702|       130| 0.0909616|       974| 0.1127326| 0.1564514|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
|h    | 0.1727494|       142| 0.1333171|       822| 0.1475089| 0.2003612|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
|g    | 0.1378641|       142| 0.1800216|      1030| 0.1173826| 0.1604393|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
|a    | 0.1669941|       170| 0.2235983|      1018| 0.1445807| 0.1913515|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
|b    | 0.1674877|       136| 0.2628284|       812| 0.1424327| 0.1949831|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
|e    | 0.1406250|       144| 0.2782384|      1024| 0.1199014| 0.1634381|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
|d    | 0.1619787|       167| 0.4368028|      1031| 0.1399947| 0.1859114|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
|c    | 0.1612903|       175| 0.4738675|      1085| 0.1398864| 0.1845487|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
|f    | 0.1481481|       200| 0.6234816|      1350| 0.1296094| 0.1682326|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
|i    | 0.1498829|       128| 0.8123997|       854| 0.1265978| 0.1756130|Exact binomial test |two.sided   |
```

I am unclear if performing a binomial test is the best method here for what I want to do, or if I am doing the binom test correctly (i.e. should I be asking whether a users error.rate falls in the population confidence interval, rather than the other way round).

Answer (score 1):

The R code part of this question is off-topic.

The statistics part, if I understand it correctly, is comparing 10 users to each other. For this, you can use regression with "user" as an independent variable. Since the dependent variable is a proportion, you can use beta regression.

Comment: The real issue concerns controlling decision error rates in the *post hoc* testing.  How would that be accomplished in a Beta regression framework?  Exactly what tests should be conducted?

Comment: That would depend on exactly what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: I want to compare the user sub-pop to the population for differences and report (effect, confidence, p). At present I build a 95CI around each user and compare the user to the all.users mean. But I am double counting (the user and the user in the whole pop.), is this correct ?                @Peter Flow, why would I use beta distrib. over binomial in this instance ?

Comment: You want regression because your problem is whether a dependent variable is related to an independent variable.  Beta regression is good when the DV is bounded, as yours is by 0 and 1.